# How to read plain text file using RTFEditorKit?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am creating a simple Wordpad editor application. I am using JTextPane. I have added code to read '.rtf' file using RTFEditorKit. Initialization code:

```
RTFEditorKit rtfKit = new RTFEditorKit();
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setEditorKit(rtfKit);
```

Now I need to read plain text file '.txt' using 'RTFEditorKit' into the same JTextPane, so that I can view plain text file and rtf file in the same application. How can I achieve this?

My application minimal code:

```
import static java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.MutableAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit;

public class MyNotepad implements ActionListener {
    public JFrame frame;
    public JPanel panel;
    public JTextPane textPane;
    public RTFEditorKit rtf;
    public StyleContext styleContext;
    public Document document;
    public JScrollPane scrollPane;
    public JMenuBar menuBar;
    public JMenu fileMenu;
    public JMenuItem newSubMenu;
    public JMenuItem openSubMenu;
    public JFileChooser fc;
    public boolean openFileExtFlag = true;
    public boolean saveFileExtFlag = true;
    public File openFile;
    public File saveFile;
    public boolean saveWindowTitle = false;
    public boolean openFileFlag;
    public boolean saveFileFlag;
    public boolean saved = true;
    public boolean dontSaveOption;
    public BufferedReader br;
    public boolean saveForNewOpenExitListener;
    public boolean saveAsFlag;
    public int returnVal;
    public String filePath;
    public boolean flagForOpenListener;
    public StyledDocument styledDocument;
    public Style defaultStyle;
    public MutableAttributeSet mas;

    public MyNotepad() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame = new JFrame("My Notepad");
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());                                                      

        rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
        textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditorKit(rtf);
        textPane.setMargin(new Insets(10,5,5,5));
        styleContext = new StyleContext();
        mas = textPane.getInputAttributes();
        styledDocument = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        textPane.setDocument(styledDocument);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(textPane);
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        newSubMenu = new JMenuItem("New");
        newSubMenu.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('N', CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
        openSubMenu = new JMenuItem("Open...");
        openSubMenu.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('O', CTRL_DOWN_MASK));

        defaultStyle = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext().getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
        fc= new JFileChooser();

        openSubMenu.addActionListener(this);
        newSubMenu.addActionListener(this);

        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,500));

        fileMenu.add(newSubMenu);
        fileMenu.add(openSubMenu);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        textPane.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(new JLabel(" "), BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(new JLabel(" "), BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(new JLabel(" "), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900,200));
        frame.pack();
        textPane.requestFocus();                                                
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyNotepad();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if ((ae.getSource() == openSubMenu)) {      
            openActionListener();
        } 
    }

    public boolean openActionListener() {
        if (openFileExtFlag && saveFileExtFlag) {
            fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Rich Text File (*.rtf)", "rtf"));
            fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text File (*.txt)", "txt"));
            openFileExtFlag = false;
        }

        do {
            returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);                               
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                openFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                filePath = openFile.getPath();
                if (openFile.exists()) {
                    break;
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "File not found, please verify the file name and the path", "Cannot open", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } while (true);


        try {
            System.out.println("---opening document...");

            textPane.setText("");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            System.out.println("Opening file - " + filePath);

            if (filePath.endsWith(".rtf")) {
                rtf.read(in, textPane.getDocument(), 0);
                in.close();
            } else if (filePath.endsWith(".txt")) {
                textPane = new JTextPane();
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
                textPane.read(fileReader, openFile);
                fileReader.close();
            }
            textPane.requestFocus();
            textPane.setCaretPosition(0);
            frame.setTitle("My Notepad  " + "- " + filePath);
            System.out.println("----File opened successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Cannot open, Invalid RTF file", "Cannot open", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can add text to a ``JTextPane``. So yes, it's possible.

Comment: Hi, I have given the minimal code, could you please suggest me, what is wrong with this code? because I can read '.rtf' file but '.txt' files cannot be read.

Comment: Could you tel us what is going on? Do you have an error?

Comment: No, I dont get any error, while opening .txt file the contents are not displaying in textpane, it is blank, but if I open .rtf file it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
textPane = new JTextPane();
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
textPane.read(fileReader, openFile);
fileReader.close();
```

You are creating a new JTextPane which will never be added to the UI, and the text is added inside this very textPane instead of the one you see in the UI...

Just remove the line : `textPane = new JTextPane();`

Sorry for late answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but even after I removed that line, I cannot read plain text file.

Comment: Before reading do `setContentType("text/plain")` or for RTF `"text/rtf"`.